# Unable to change canvas css

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am working with HTML And css, i have canvas(showing line graph), But i want to change "background color" and some other css changes,How cna i do this ? Here is my current code

```
<div class="chartContainer" id="canvas" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script>
canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
</script>
```

Comment: You can't see the background of the canvas behind the filled blue rectangle.

Comment: @Teemu Just want to know how can i change in existing canvas css,Hope you understand my point

Comment: Just like you change CSS of any element, change/add/remove a class.

Comment: Your canvas is not showing a line graph, it's showing a big blue rectangle. [Edit] your question so that it contains enough details for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

With your code I can see that you are using some library (i.e. Chart.js or Echarts etc)

In these libraries where CANVAS is used to draw Charts **Styling is not done with css**, Instead you have to make changes **inside script**.

---

Could you be more specific about what changes you want to do & which Library or Reference you are using ?? So that I can tell you exactly what and where to change !!

---

**UPDATE**

@Rick - **Please find code for Changing Styles:**

1- For Changing Marker(red) & Line Colors(blue) Use like this :

```
const Mychart = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderColor: 'blue',
        }]
    }
});
```

2- For changing Canvas Background in Chart.js There is no built-in method but you can try if below codes works :

```
ctx.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,128,0,1)';
```

or you may also set css Backgroundcolor on canvas.

But as a Designer I will never recommend using Color on Background of Any Chart, you should make it Default White Color only.

ONE MORE SUGGESTION, Use Echarts Library It is highly Customizable
Look at this Example : [ECharts 4.0 - Line Chart with Toolbox and Theme](https://codepen.io/WebCodePro/pen/WNNYBjK)

Comment: i want to change background color, add some button etc...

Comment: "With your code I can see that you are using some library". How do you see that? There is nothing in OP's code that shows they're using a library of any sort.

Comment: Oky you can do this, Just tell me the library you are using CHART.JS or ECHART.js ?

you can find in your head tags like :  <script src="echarts.js"></script>

Comment: @Kaiido , I can see with the script which he is using, these are library references only, I know about Charts very well.

Comment: @KRISHNA: name of file is "chart.js"

Comment: @Rick : Some Suggestion has been Updated Above